# Jquery Ajax Load page show live results

Tags: php, ajax, load, live

Simple page with a Submit button **id='testDo'**

When clicked I'm trying to show a hidden span **id='DOImg'**

The I'm trying to call an external php page **doip.php** passing the value from one form field **id='DO'**

This is my jquery :

```
$("#testDO").click(function () {    
    $('#DOImg').show();  
    $("#DOstatus").load("doit.php?DO=" + $("#DO").val());
    $('#DOImg').hide();  
});
```

The idea is as the **doit.php** page runs the output is returned to the **DOstatus** textarea.

doit.php contains :

```
$doval = $_REQUEST['do'];       
$cmd = "php testdo.php $doval";
system("$cmd 2>&1", $out);
echo $out
```

This works, but I don't get the results until testdo.php has completed.

If I run testdo.php page manually at the command line I get each line of output as it happens, but if I run it directly via my browser I get everything at completion.

testdo.php is logging into remote devices and checking uptime. The output returned is:

```
1 - IPAddress - Uptime
2 - IPAddress - Uptime
3 - IPAddress - Uptime
```

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks :D

**UPDATE**

I've updated testdo.php so it now output each line when called from the browser or commandline.

It's not helped though !

Comment: you could use an `iframe` or set the ajax response to `async:false`

Comment: or try using events, like pub sub. or observer pattern

Comment: Tried adding async:false and it didn't help. Not heard of these events before, can you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: original post updated.